# How to hide element once receive and find particular class? it's jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Please help me today with following: 
**My 1. step:**

```
<div id="htmlData">         
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="pull-left">
           <h3>Report: <strong>Travel </strong></h3>
                <h3>Total Bookings: <strong>240</strong> | Customer Bookings: <strong>20</strong></h3>
                <p>The following report presents a graphical view of all travel booked.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right pdfhide" style="margin-right:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-md-6 pdfhide" style="margin-right:-0px !important;">
                                        <div class="input-group input-large date-picker input-daterange" data-date="10/11/2012" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime("-1 month"));?>">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon pdfhide">
                                            to </span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime("+1 day"));?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /input-group -->

                                    </div>                  
        </div>

        </div>
```

**My 2. Step:**
On javascript side I am access above html code through `id="htmlData"` and then find particular class called `pdfhide` where you find this type of class add `style="display: none;"` into the html code and then pass them through ajax to other php page where I will do simply echo `$_POST['html_data']`.

```
if($('#htmlData').find('.pdfhide').length != 0) {
                            $('#htmlData').find('.pdfhide').innerHTML = "style='display: none;'";
                            alert(htmlData);
                        } else {
                            alert('oh no');
                        }

                        $("#loader").show("slow");

                        $.ajax({

                            url: 'print_html.php',
                            type: 'POST',

                            data: {html_data: htmlData},//original....
                            success: function(data){
                                alert(data);
                            }, error: function() {
                                alert('Found error!');
                            }
                        });
```

So friends, I want simply to inject `style="display:none"` to find elements which have a class `"pdfhide"` and then after injecting pass it to the **printout_html.php** page. Be note: when i will printout them on **printout_html.php** page it should not display those hide elements.:)

Thanks in advanced I know people out there are so smart coder:) who can help me out in this silly things.:)

Comment: do you wanna hide element using Display property

Comment: what specific data you are trying to send?

Answer (score 0):

You can use : `.hide()` function of jquery

Like  : `$('#htmlData').find('.pdfhide').hide();`

**Updated code should look like**

```
                if($('#htmlData').find('.pdfhide').length != 0) {
                        $('#htmlData').find('.pdfhide').hide();
                        alert(htmlData);
                        $("#loader").show("slow");

                    $.ajax({

                        url: 'print_html.php',
                        type: 'POST',

                        data: {html_data: htmlData},//original....
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }, error: function() {
                            alert('Found error!');
                        }
                     });
                  } else {
                        alert('oh no');
                  }
```

Comment: Hi, it's not working because i don't won't to hide() element here but inject style display:none to the html code so that when I will display that html code to next page it will hide those elements.

Comment: hide() automatically add display:none to element which has `.pdfhide` class. You can inspect that element and check for the same...

Comment: Hi It will only hide that element on the current page not on the print_html.php page and i want some solution that when send data to print_html.php page at that time which ever element I assign as display:none should not be appear into print_html.php

Answer (score 0):

try this :

$('#htmlData').find('.pdfhide').css( "display", "none" );

Comment: Bro I tried this and it's not work for me sorry:( any other idea

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can try either add new class or

.css()

1st one you can add class,

> $('#htmlData').find('.pdfhide').addClass('abcd');

2nd add css will remove existing css

> var asdf = $('#htmlData').find('.pdfhide');
>
> $('#htmlData').find('.pdfhide').css('display',"none");

also you have multiple same class so that may lead you some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a array of Element use this

```
  $('#htmlData').find('.pdfhide').each(function (inde) {
  $(this).css( "display", "none" );
//Or use this
//$(this).attr("style","display:none");
});
```

i hope this help

Answer (score 0):

you can add style using following code

```
$(".pdfhide").css("display","none");
```

but you have added pdfhide class to every element except input element.Parent div it will hide all element who are child don't require add all of them to hide all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code.

```
 var htmlData = $('div').find('div.pdfhide').html();
        if(htmlData.length != 0) {
                        $('div').find('div.pdfhide').css('display','none');
                        console.log(htmlData);
                    } else {
                        alert('oh no');
                    }
                   $("#loader").show("slow");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'print_html.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {html_data: htmlData},
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }, error: function() {
                            alert('Found error!');
                        }
                    });
```

I think you also have problem in sending the htmlData. So please try this one I think it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
Give ID and style display to your div i.e.

```
<div class="pull-right pdfhide" id="pdfhide" style="margin-right:0px !important;display:block">
 //Your code
 </div>
```

Use this script

```
document.getElementById("pdfhide").style.display = "none";
```

I hope it will help you.